# how to import modular package on Echarts?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, echarts

I wonder how to import modular package on Echarts? i've read their documentation in this link,

[Echarts Documentation](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts/doc/doc-en.html#Import-ECharts)

but i still dont know how to, 
where i have to put that code?

```
require.config({
packages: [
    {
        name: 'echarts',
        location: '../../src',
        main: 'echarts'
    },
    {
        name: 'zrender',
        location: '../../../zrender/src', 
        main: 'zrender'
    }
]
});
```

and this is code for my Chart :

```
var option = {
tooltip : {
    trigger: 'axis'
},
legend: {
    data:['a','b']
},
toolbox: {
    show : true,
    feature : {
        mark : {show: true},
        dataView : {readOnly:false},
        magicType : {show: true, type: ['line', 'bar', 'stack', 'tiled']},
        restore : {show: true},
        saveAsImage : {show: true}
    }
},
calculable : true,
dataZoom : {
    show : true,
    realtime : true,
    start : 40,
    end : 60
},
xAxis : [
    {
        type : 'category',
        boundaryGap : true,
        data : ['sorong','papua','banjarmasin']
    }
],
yAxis : [
    {
        type : 'value'
    }
],
series : [

    {
        name:'b',
        type:'bar',
        data:[23,34,56]
    }
]
};

var ecConfig = require('echarts/config');
function eConsole(param) {
    var mes = '';
    if (typeof param.seriesIndex != 'undefined') {
    window.open("/"+param.name, '_blank');
    win.focus(); 
}
if (param.type == 'hover') {
    document.getElementById('hover-console').innerHTML = 'Event Console : ' + mes;
}
else {
    document.getElementById('console').innerHTML = mes;
}
console.log(param);
}

return myChart.setOption(option).on(ecConfig.EVENT.CLICK, eConsole);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should see the text below the documentation.

```
//from echarts example
```

`...
<script src="./js/echarts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require.config({
        paths: {
            echarts: './js/dist'
        }
    });
    require(
        [
            'echarts',
            'echarts/chart/line',   // load-on-demand, don't forget the Magic switch type.
            'echarts/chart/bar'
        ],
        function (ec) {
            var myChart = ec.init(document.getElementById('main'));
            var option = {
                ...
            }
            myChart.setOption(option);
        }
    );
</script>`